# Transfer files from PC into React Native App

Tags: ios, react-native, file-transfer

Sometimes I see (mostly iOS) apps, that serve their own HTTP content, which can be accessed with browser on local network in order to transfer files, for example certain audio or video players. In Android world, this is not so much an issue, since the user can access device filesystem using USB cable, but this is not possible on iOS.

Is there any tutorial/best practice/other resource providing deeper insight into this topic? I already did some research and tried to discover some tools for this purpose, but I did not find anything describing exactly this use-case.
Could somebody give me a hint, where to get started?